# TFS - Is it possible to impersonate someone to check-in changes?

Tags: branch, impersonation, checkin

I'm responsible for merging and commiting changes to the test Branch, but by doing that every check-in is marked as me as the author. So until now i'm writting the author name in the comments. But it's ugly.

Is it possible to impersonate someone else when doing check-in? What are the security permissions needed in order to do that?

I'm using Team Foundation Server 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TFS API Part 29 – TFS Impersonation](https://web.archive.org/web/20100827231910/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2010/08/23/tfs-api-part-29-tfs-impersonation.aspx)

> TFS Impersonation is a feature that
> was introduced in TFS 2010 in order to
> allow a process running as User A to
> make web service calls to TFS in such
> a way that TFS thinks the actions are
> being performed by User B.

[Using TFS Impersonation with the Version Control Client APIs](https://web.archive.org/web/20100718090732/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylaf/archive/2010/03/29/using-tfs-impersonation-with-the-version-control-client-apis.aspx)

> how to use the version control client
> APIs to create workspaces and check in
> files [...] with TFS Impersonation to
> record the check ins as if they had
> been done by a different user
>
> in order for impersonation to work,
> the user that the process is running
> as must have the “Make requests on
> behalf of others” permission for this
> collection

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [runas command](http://www.computerhope.com/runas.htm) from a command prompt and either run VS from the command line or use the [command line version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e.aspx) of check-in, merge, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can't do that, as I would need everyone's password to use runas. I was thinking of a more direct approach.